# Choose distinct users from one table and latest date on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table_01:

```
----------------
ROW_ID | NAME   
----------------
11223  | Frank      
11224  | Frank
11225  | James
11226  | James
11227  | Joe
11228  | Joe
11229  | Joe
11230  | Tom
11231  | Tom
11232  | Tom
```

Table_02:

```
--------------------------------------------------
ROW_ID | NAME   | EVENT_DATE    | EVENT_LOCATION
--------------------------------------------------
11106  | Frank  | 27/01/2017    | London
11109  | Frank  | 19/01/2017    | Munich
11105  | James  | 27/01/2017    | New York
11110  | James  | 02/01/2017    | L.A
11101  | Joe    | 27/01/2017    | Paris
11104  | Joe    | 26/01/2017    | Barcelona
11107  | Joe    | 31/01/2017    | Tokyo
11102  | Tom    | 24/01/2017    | Prague
11103  | Tom    | 03/01/2017    | Lisbon
11108  | Tom    | 20/01/2017    | Dublin
```

I would like to query **Table_01** for distinct users, and also know their most recent EVENT_DATE and EVENT_LOCATION from **Table_02**

Answer:

```
---------------------------------------------------
NAME    | NAME    | EVENT_DATE   | EVENT_LOCATION
---------------------------------------------------
Frank   | Frank   | 27/01/2017   | London
James   | James   | 27/01/2017   | New York
Joe     | Joe     | 31/01/2017   | Tokyo
Tom     | Tom     | 24/01/2017   | Prague
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2016. Compatibility level: SQL Server 2005 (90)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t2.*
from (select distinct name from table_01) n join
     (select t2.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by name order by event_date desc) as seqnum
      from table_02 t2
     ) t2
     on n.name = t2.name and t2.seqnum = 1.
```

You don't really seem to need `table_01` for this, unless you want it for filtering:

```
select t2.*
from (select t2.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by name order by event_date desc) as seqnum
      from table_02 t2
     ) t2
where t2.seqnum = 1.
```

Comment: whats the difference between table_02 and t2?

Comment: `t2` is an alias for `table_02`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how the two tables join except for on `name`.

There are many ways to do this. Here are some of them:

[**`with common_table_expression as ()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) using **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**

```
with cte as (
  select  u.Name, e.Event_Date, e.Event_Location
      , rn = row_number() over (
              partition by u.Name
              order by e.[Event_Date] desc
            )
    from (select distinct Name from table_01) u
      left join table_02 e
        on u.Name = e.Name
)
select Name, Event_Location, Event_Date
  from cte
  where rn = 1
```

---

Subquery instead of `cte`:

```
select Name, Event_Location, Event_Date
from (
  select  u.Name, e.Event_Date, e.Event_Location
      , rn = row_number() over (
              partition by u.Name
              order by e.[Event_Date] desc
            )
    from (select distinct Name from table_01) u
      left join table_02 e
        on u.Name = e.Name
  ) as sub
where rn = 1
```

---

**`cross` [`apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)** version:

```
 select distinct
     u.Name
   , e.Event_Location
   , e.[Event_Date]
  from (select distinct Name from table_01) u
    cross apply (
      select top 1
            Event_Date
          , Event_Location
        from table_02 e
        where e.Name =u.Name
        order by e.Event_Date desc
       ) as e;
```

---

**[`top with ties`](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)** version:

```
select top 1 with ties
    u.Name, e.Event_Date, e.Event_Location
from (select distinct Name from table_01) u
  left join table_02 e
    on u.Name = e.Name
  order by 
    row_number() over (
      partition by u.Name
          order by e.Event_Date desc
      )
```

Comment: name is the only connecting row.